# When do I share data from fragment it close?

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I share data from a fragment, it closes the activity/fragment. I searched, but I did not figure out the reason for that.

It does send my text as I want, but I do not want my fragment to close.
Below is my code:

```
 sharRec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s = arr.get(position).getTitle() +
                        arr.get(position).getQuantities() +
                        arr.get(position).getRecipe() +
                       + arr.get(position).getTime() +
                        +arr.get(position).getNum();

                imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName()
                        + "/drawable/" + arr.get(position).getImg());

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "share");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s);
                sendIntent.setType("*/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Share using"));
            }
```

Comment: can you post your exception?

Comment: post your onPause & onResume methods too

Comment: @AnbarasuChinna it did not any crash it just close the fragment but i solve it thank you

Comment: @Royz thank you so much i solve it the problem  was in onPause i was do these line :       FragmentUnits.replacerFragment(this, R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment());  which i deleted now .

Comment: Glad it helped :)